# Можно ли как-то вычислить адрес в шаблоне django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, шаблоны, django-template

Нахождясь на определенной странице нужно вывести информацию через условие по адресу этой самой страницы.
Подскажите, есть какие-то способы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Получить в шаблоне текущий адрес:

```
{{ request.path }}
```

Текущий адрес и параметры:

```
{{ request.get_full_path }}
```

Домен, адрес и параметры:

```
{{ request.build_absolute_uri }}
```

Примеры результатов:

```
/main/
/main/?q=test
http://127.0.0.1:8000/main/?q=test
```

Comment: Спасибо! Мне уже подсказали. ))